# Property 'A' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'C'

Tags: typescript, types, material-ui, react-admin

I'm fairly new to Typescript and I've run into an error that I don't really understand. I managed to fix it (I think), but I'm just curious to really understand what the error is saying.

Here is the error:

```
TypeScript error in /home/js/Development/gigalixir-web/src/RegisterPage.tsx(155,42):
Argument of type 'typeof Login' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyComponent<Pick<StyledComponentProps<"main" | "avatar" | "icon" | "card"> & Partial<WithTheme>, "theme"> & Partial<WithTheme> & { classes: Record<"main" | "avatar" | "icon" | "card", string>; }>'.
  Type 'typeof Login' is not assignable to type 'new (props: Pick<StyledComponentProps<"main" | "avatar" | "icon" | "card"> & Partial<WithTheme>, "theme"> & Partial<WithTheme> & { classes: Record<"main" | "avatar" | "icon" | "card", string>; }) => Component<...>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Property 'loginForm' is missing in type 'Pick<StyledComponentProps<"main" | "avatar" | "icon" | "card"> & Partial<WithTheme>, "theme"> & Partial<WithTheme> & { classes: Record<"main" | "avatar" | "icon" | "card", string>; }' but required in type 'Readonly<Props & Partial<WithTheme> & { classes: Record<"main" | "avatar" | "icon" | "card", string>; } & HtmlHTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>'.  TS2345

    153 | }
    154 | 
  > 155 | const EnhancedLogin = withStyles(styles)(Login) as ComponentType<Props>
        |                                          ^
    156 | 
    157 | // EnhancedLogin.propTypes = {
    158 | //   backgroundImage: PropTypes.string,
```

Which is from [this file](https://github.com/jesseshieh/gigalixir-web/blob/2740439fa860b107b361fb3fa43ee6788a6223d0/src/RegisterPage.tsx).

I ended up fixing it, or at least I think so, by changing `object` on [this line](https://github.com/jesseshieh/gigalixir-web/blob/2740439fa860b107b361fb3fa43ee6788a6223d0/src/RegisterPage.tsx#L33) to `Theme` which matches [this line](https://github.com/jesseshieh/gigalixir-web/blob/2740439fa860b107b361fb3fa43ee6788a6223d0/src/RegisterPage.tsx#L37). It makes sense to me that those types should match, but I guess my questions are

1. Why does the error above mention `loginForm` when the error has to do with `theme`
2. Why does the error not occur [here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v2.9.6/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/auth/Login.tsx#L28), where I copy and pasted this code from.

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!